# Multiple parents for a child in familytree chart in GOJS

Tags: javascript, family-tree, gojs

How can I add multiple parent for a child node in family tree diagram in GOJS. Are there any parameters or any lines of codes to do so ?

I want to generate image like below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like http://gojs.net/latest/samples/genogram.html? That is what most people use when they want to show both parents as separate nodes, potentially each with their own relationships.

The http://gojs.net/latest/samples/familyTree.html sample uses a **TreeModel**, not a **GraphLinksModel**, so it cannot describe a graph where nodes might have multiple "tree" parents.  You have to use a **GraphLinksModel** for what you describe.

Furthermore, that Family Tree sample uses **TreeLayout**, which only works well on tree-structured graphs.  You want to use **LayeredDigraphLayout** instead.

So to get what you have drawn, use a **GraphLinksModel** and **LayeredDigraphLayout**.

Comment: I am using family tree and I am able to generate others except "Grandmother".. I hope the figure clearifies you.